# how to console.log html tag attribute's value with hyphen in the middle in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I would need some help about this attribute:

```
<script id="mysdk" src="https://www.myscript.com/sdk/js?currency=EUR" this-client-token="nsiYXV0aG9yaXphdGlvbkZpbmdlcnByaW50IjoiZGUyYjM4N2FiZWV"></script>
```

What I'm trying to do is to console.log this-client-token in this way:

```
    var el = document.getElementById("mysdk");
    console.log(el.this-client-token);
```

This because, after making this work, I will be finally able to change the value of this-client-token, since that is my purpose. But I get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: client is not defined

I have no idea why I get this error, is it because of the hyphen? any suggestion?

Thank you!

Elliot

Comment: `el.getAttribute('this-client-token')`

Comment: Of course it's because of the hyphen. Hyphen is for subtraction in JavaScript, it's trying to subtract `client` from `el.this`.

Comment: You also shouldn't make up your own attributes in HTML. If you need application-specific attributes, use `data-XXX`. These are put in the `dataset` property, and the hyphens are converted to camelCase. So if you have `data-client-token` it will become `.dataset.clientToken`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much, actually I followed your suggestion about getAttribute and I also used setAttribute and it was exactly what I needed. I don't know how could I contribute with a positive feedback to your answer here, I would be glad to do. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `-` is subtraction. It's trying to calculate `el.this - client - token`, which fails because none of these variables exist.

Change to a `data-XXX` attribute, and use the `dataset` property.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("mysdk");
console.log(el.dataset.clientToken);
```

```html
<script id="mysdk" src="https://www.myscript.com/sdk/js?currency=EUR" data-client-token="nsiYXV0aG9yaXphdGlvbkZpbmdlcnByaW50IjoiZGUyYjM4N2FiZWV"></script>
```

If you can't change the attribute (because it's required by the SDK script, which you can't change) you can use `el.getAttribute("this-client-token")`